# Solspace calendar 500 error

Tags: solspace-calendar, error-500

I have index template for my events like so:

```
{!--------------------------------------------------
              SHOW DAY LISTING
--------------------------------------------------}
{if segment_2=="day"}
{embed="events/_view-day"}

{!--------------------------------------------------
          SHOW THE SPECIFIC MONTH
--------------------------------------------------}

{if:elseif segment_1=="events" AND segment_2=="month"}
{embed="events/_view-month"}


{!--------------------------------------------------
          SHOW CALENDAR VIEW (index)
--------------------------------------------------}

{if:elseif segment_2=="cal"}
{embed="events/calendar"}

{!--------------------------------------------------
              SHOW THE CURRENT MONTH
--------------------------------------------------}
{if:else}
 {embed="events/_view-current-month}
 {/if}
```

I have this exact, advanced calendar implementation on the 3rd rule here at /events/cal
http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/month//#examples

The strange thing is I'm using this template base for 5 sites. Only one of them is experiencing issues with the 500 error. My log has:

```
[Thu May 01 11:35:35 2014] [warn] [client 174.59.51.74] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45     seconds, referer: http://figlancaster.com/events/month/06/2014
[Thu May 01 11:35:35 2014] [error] [client 174.59.51.74] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://figlancaster.com/events/month/06/2014
```

I tried logging in as root and bumped up the settings per this article:

[mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds --> Premature end of script headers: admin.php](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-45-seconds-premature-end-of-script-headers)

However, still no difference.

All of the php memory limits for all the site using this template base is 256M

Any thoughts? This is driving me nuts.

**Update**: My /events/calendar template. The only modification I made was the segments for the date range.

```
    <div id="fc_calendar">
        {exp:calendar:cal
        {if segment_3 == ''}
            date_range_start="year-month-01"
            date_range_end="year-month-last"
        {/if}
        {if segment_3 != ""}
            date_range_start="{segment_5}-{segment_4}-01"
            date_range_end="{segment_5}-{segment_4}-last"
        {/if}
        }
        {display_each_month}

         <div id="month-header">

     <div class="last_month"> 
           <a href="{path='/events/cal/month'}/{prev_month format="%m/%Y"}/">
                            {prev_month format="%F"}
                        </a>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 60%; text-align: center;">
               <h2>{date format="%F %Y"}</h2>
        </div>
        <div  class="next_month">
          <a href="{path='/events/cal/month'}/{next_month format="%m/%Y"}/">
                            {next_month format="%F"}
                        </a>
        </div>


     <br style="clear:both">
     </div>



                        <div class="wrap">
                            <table id="fc_inner">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr id="days_of_week">
                                        {display_each_day_of_week}
                                        <th class="day_of_week {day_of_week}">
                                            {day_of_week}
                                        </th>
                                        {/display_each_day_of_week}
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {display_each_week}
                                     <tr>
                                        {display_each_day}
                                        {if day_in_current_month}
                                            <td class="day_cell">
                                                <div class="date">

                                                        {date format="%j"}

                                                </div>
                                        {if:else}
                                            <td class="day_cell out_of_range">
                                                <div class="date">
                                                <span class="num">
                                                    {date format="%j"}
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        {/if}
                                        {display_each_hour}
                                            {events}
                                                <div
                                                  class="
                                                    event {if event_all_day}all_day{/if}
                                                    {if event_multi_day}multi_day{/if}
                                                    {if event_first_day}first_day{/if}
                                                    {if event_last_day}last_day{/if}
                                                    {if all_day_event_index_difference > 0}
                                                        index_difference_{all_day_event_index_difference}
                                                    {/if}
                                                  ">
                                                {if event_multi_day}
                                                    {if event_all_day == FALSE}
                                                        {if event_first_day}
                                                            {event_start_time}
                                                        {/if}
                                                        {if event_last_day}
                                                            {event_end_time}
                                                        {/if}
                                                    {/if}
                                                    <a href="{path='calendar/events'}/{event_id}/">{event_title}</a>
                                                {if:else}
                                                    {if event_all_day == ''}
                                                        {event_start_date format="%g"}
                                                        {if event_start_minute > 0}
                                                            :{event_start_minute}
                                                        {/if}
                                                        {if event_end_time != event_start_time && event_end_time != '00:00'}
                                                            &ndash;
                                                            {event_end_date format="%g"}
                                                            {if event_end_minute > 0}
                                                                :{event_end_minute}
                                                            {/if}
                                                            {event_end_date format="%a"}
                                                        {if:else}
                                                            {event_start_date format="%a"}
                                                        {/if}
                                                    {/if}
                                                     <a href="/events/view/{url_title}/">{event_title}</a>
                                                {/if}
                                                </div>
                                                {/events}
                                            {/display_each_hour}
                                        </td>
                                        {/display_each_day}
                                    </tr>
                                    {/display_each_week}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

        {/display_each_month}
        {/exp:calendar:cal}
    </div>
```

Non-working URL: http://figlancaster.com/events/cal
Note: This is a list view of the events I"m attempting to load into the calendar. There are probably roughly 150 or so:
http://figlancaster.com/events
Working URL loading the same template but less events: 
http://www.figbethlehem.com/events/cal

Both sites are running EE v2.5.2 and Calendar 1.8.6

Comment: You're using an **advanced conditional**, which means **all** embeds are being called. If in each embed template, you have complex Calendar code, or simply a large number of event data, this could slow down the page enough to give you the 500 error. Consider using another method to avoid advanced conditionals, such as using **simple conditionals** (see EE docs for details), or a plugin that prevents all embeds from loading, such as Stash or Switchee.

Comment: If the issue is a specific embed/piece of code, try using each embed, **alone**, on the template until you have one that causes the 500 error. Then, note the URL, code, and Calendar version that you are using, and add this info by editing this OP.

Comment: I know which template it is. It's the event/calendar template. I made edits to my original post to show the actual problematic template.

Comment: Would Template Morsels help maybe?

Comment: I tried the above code on a template, and didn't have issues. If you put the code in `event/calendar` **alone**, on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code, do you get the 500 error? How much PHP memory do you have set up? Have you tried increasing it? If the issue is a performance issue (eg. too slow to load all data), Template Morsels could be useful, but always make sure you optimized your templates as much as possible before that.

Comment: When loading the events/calendar by itself with just the advanced implementation example on your site I still receive a 500 error. I have my server configured with these settings (256M (also tried 512M)) http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-45-seconds-premature-end-of-script-headers

Comment: How many events do you have in a month? If you have *many* (let's say a few hundred or thousands), you might need more memory. Anything in your server error logs that might give a hint about the error (500 is pretty generic)? You might want to open a ticket at support.solspace.com. Please give the usual information that helps us troubleshoot: CP/FTP login credentials, the URL where we can see the issue, the template used with the URL, EE/Calendar versions, the type of error you're getting (blank page, PHP error...), etc.